# tmpl_if what is this and how can I work on this easily on a code editor?

Tags: html, templates, editor

I'm involved in a new project. When I opened the first page, I noticed various tags like: `<TMPL_IF>some code</TMPL_IF>`.
There are quite straight forward and in a couple of hours I was able to do loops and conditional programming, everything is fine but I would like to understand some things about those tags:

Where these tags come from? Are they html? Or something different? Are an extension given by some sort of library on the server?

How can I make my code editor (read Dreamweaver, or jedit) make understand those tags and make the code highlight working again?

May I use those tags in all pages? I mean, I have some sites that could really have improovements with the use of those tags... I have search on the web, and I have seen that there are a bunch of them, from loops to unless conditions, really really nice, but I haven't find a place that teach them from scrap.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Seen this? http://search.cpan.org/~wonko/HTML-Template-2.95/lib/HTML/Template.pm

Comment: yes, it is the first place i have found... is it the "real porject"? it sounded like a personal project of that michael... i thought it was like an emulation of the "real" template feature... nice tu know it is the real beginning. thanks!!!